# Multi-line variables remove new line character - Fish

Tags: shell, fish

When I set any multiline text as a variable in fish, it removes the new line characters and replaces them with space, how can I stop it from doing that? Minimal complete example:

```
~ ) set lines (cat .lorem); set start 2; set end 4;
~ ) cat .lorem 
once upon a midnight dreary while i pondered weak and weary
over many a quaint and curious volume of forgotten lore
while i nodded nearly napping suddenly there came a tapping
as of some one gently rapping rapping at my chamber door
tis some visiter i muttered tapping at my chamber door
~ ) cat .lorem | sed -ne $start\,{$end}p\;{$end}q  # Should print lines 2..4
over many a quaint and curious volume of forgotten lore
while i nodded nearly napping suddenly there came a tapping
as of some one gently rapping rapping at my chamber door
~ ) echo $lines
once upon a midnight dreary while i pondered weak and weary over many a quaint and curious volume of forgotten lore while i nodded nearly napping     suddenly there came a tapping as of some one gently rapping rapping at my chamber door tis some visiter i muttered tapping at my chamber door
```

Comment: try `echo "$lines" (or the fish eqivalent of dbl-quoting a variable name). Good luck.

Comment: @shellter Still the same.

Comment: known issue: https://github.com/fish-shell/fish-shell/issues/159

Comment: btw, `printf "%s\n" $lines`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

fish splits command substitutions on newlines. This means that `$lines` is a list. You can read more [about lists here](http://fishshell.com/docs/current/tutorial.html#tut_lists).

When you pass a list to a command, each entry in the list becomes a separate argument. `echo` space-separates its arguments. That explains the behavior you're seeing.

Note that other shells do the same thing here. For example, in bash:

```
lines=$(cat .lorem)
echo $lines
```

If you want to prevent the splitting, you can temporarily set IFS to empty:

```
begin
   set -l IFS
   set lines (cat .lorem)
end
echo $lines
```

now `$lines` will contain newlines.

As faho says, `read` can also be used and is a little shorter:

```
read -z lines < ~/.lorem
echo $lines
```

but consider whether splitting on newlines might actually be what you want. As faho hinted, your `sed` script can be replaced with array slices:

```
set lines (cat .lorem)
echo $lines[2..4] # prints lines 2 through 4
```

Comment: this is the old way… see @wataash answers below for the new and new new ways

Answer (score 7):

From fish 3.4, we can use `"$(innercommand)"` syntax.

```bash
set lines "$(echo -e 'hi\nthere')"
set -S lines
# $lines: set in global scope, unexported, with 1 elements
# $lines[1]: |hi\nthere|
```

- https://fishshell.com/docs/current/relnotes.html
- https://fishshell.com/docs/current/language.html#command-substitution

Answer (score 1):

Pipe it to `string split0`.

```
set lines (echo -e 'hi\nthere')
set -S lines
# $lines: set in global scope, unexported, with 2 elements
# $lines[1]: length=2 value=|hi|
# $lines[2]: length=5 value=|there|

set lines (echo -e 'hi\nthere' | string split0)
set -S lines
# $lines: set in global scope, unexported, with 1 elements
# $lines[1]: length=9 value=|hi\nthere\n|
```

This is noted in [the document](https://fishshell.com/docs/current/language.html#command-substitution):

> If the output is piped to string split or string split0 as the last step, those splits are used as they appear instead of splitting lines.

Answer (score 0):

It is not just *removing* the newlines, it is splitting on them.

Your variable $lines is now a list, with each line being an element in that list.

See

```
set lines (cat .lorem)
for line in $lines
    echo $line
end
echo $lines[2]
printf "%s\n" $lines[2..4]
```

Comment: Thanks, I kinda knew that. I was wondering if there was a way to stop that behaviour. Another thing that's weird is that when you do `set foo bar\nblarch` then it doesn't split them, it's set as one item.

Comment: Currently, it'll split on newlines if IFS is set and _not split_ if IFS is unset (ie. it ignores the actual value of IFS). You can also use [`read -z`](http://fishshell.com/docs/current/commands.html#read).